PrimeNG- p-table Issue with virtual scroll not triggering event for big screens
Angular: 18.1.2
PrimeNG: 17.18.6
I have a p-table where the virtualscroll is triggering the event in laptop sized height (547px) but not for bigger displays like monitor (763px).
Using PrimeNG stackblitz with my parameters also gave same issue, a whitespace gap while scrolling (in the stackblitz they have loading UI otherwise it will be blank white space). Need to scroll much more to trigger the event.
Template code
<p-table #myID [columns]="myColumns" 
[value]="myValues" 
styleClass="p-datatable-striped p-datatable-something responsive-table"
 sortMode="multiple"
 [reorderableColumns]="true" 
[resizableColumns]="true" [rowHover]="true"
dataKey="myKey" 
[lazy]="true" 
(onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)" 
[responsive]="true" 
[scrollable]="true"
 [(selection)]="selectedRow" 
[(contextMenuSelection)]="selectedSomething" 
[contextMenu]="contextMenuRef" 
[rows]="20" 
[lazyLoadOnInit]="true" 
[loading]="loading" 
[scrollHeight]="tableHeight" // 547px for laptop works fine, 763px for desktop doesnt work 
[virtualScroll]="true" 
[virtualScrollItemSize]="46" 
[rowTrackBy]="trackThis" 
#someThing 
(onColReorder)="myFn($event)" 
(onSort)="onSortSomething($event)" 
[multiSortMeta]="mySort" > 

Component code
async loadLazy(event: TableLazyLoadEvent) { if (event) {

GitHub link for same:https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/3169
Please let me know for any gaps or how can it be resolved?
